# history.pushstate and HTTP POST form repost

Tags: forms, http-post, page-refresh, pushstate, html5-history

I am currently facing a little problem with HTTP post forms and history pushstate.

When my user submits a POST form in `example.com/page-1` and then clicks on a link within this page, they are redirected to `example.com/page-2` with a history.pushstate. The JS script just changes the current url, pushes the old to the history, and then displays the new content. This works perfectly fine for me.

The problem: Once the user is on `example.com/page-2` and *manually refreshes the page* (ctrl+r or refresh button), Chromes prompts the user to submit the form again; but the form was actually in `example.com/page-1` and there is no reason to asked it again in this "new" page.

Is there a way to clear all the previously-submitted data in javascript on the popstate change to prevent repost prompt from the browser? Or am I missing something with my history states? Or is it something currently not implemented by the browser well yet?

I only tested it with chrome since I don't implement pushstate with other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try replaceState instead? See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

> The `replaceState()` method
>
> history.replaceState() operates exactly like history.pushState() except that replaceState() modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one.
>
> replaceState() is particularly useful when you want to update the state object or URL of the current history entry in response to some user action.

Comment: Hi, I got the same issue with replaceState, but I now send my forms via Ajax wich solves the problem. I guess that using javascript history.pushstate and  replacestate without sending forms via ajax is not a good thing to do since its pretty easy to do so with jquery,mootools etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have an identical issue - I'm using the History API with [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/).

The solution that I have thought of is to have an intermediate page which the form redirects to after signing in. The purpose of this intermediate page is to add a non-POST page before the destination page so that the browser will not prompt to re-submit the form (and for Chrome to NOT add a redundant entry).

For your example, after submitting the POST form in `example.com/page-1` the server should redirect the user to `example.com/page-1a`

`example.com/page-1a` can verify that the user credentials are present, and then redirect to `example.com/page-2`. This will solve your problem, I believe.

For the redirection mechanism, there are 3 options that I can think of:

1. server-side redirect
2. JavaScript (`location.href="page-2"`)
3. HTML header (`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://example.com/page-2'" />`)

Personally I have tried options 1 and 2 - they work fine for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is known as POST-REDIRECT-GET (PRG for short), and is a common technique for avoiding these kinds of issues, such as re-POSTing on reload. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

After a POST is received you can redirect the user with a [303 See Other](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303) HTTP response which changes the request method to GET. Pressing reload after a 303 redirect will result in another GET request and users won't get prompted to submit the form again. I believe that is exactly what this status code is intended for.

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 303 See Other redirect status
> response code indicates that the redirects don't link to the requested
> resource itself, but to another page (such as a confirmation page, a
> representation of a real-world object — see HTTP range-14 — or an
> upload-progress page). This response code is often sent back as a
> result of PUT or POST. The method used to display this redirected page
> is always GET.